# How to set mutli-row headers in the MVC SyncFusion DataGrid?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4, syncfusion

I need multi-row/wrapped headers in my SyncFusion MVC Data Grid. I am using fabric.css.
Which style do I need to edit to allow Wrapping in the Header and/or Set the Header to multiple lines ?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the following fluent properties:

```
.AllowTextWrap(true).TextWrapSettings(text => { text.WrapMode(Syncfusion.EJ2.Grids.WrapMode.Header); })
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap header text by setting `AllowTextWrap` and `TextWrapSettings.WrapMode` as `WrapMode.Header`.

References:

https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetmvc/documentation/grid/cell/#auto-wrap

https://help.syncfusion.com/cr/aspnetmvc-js2/Syncfusion.EJ2~Syncfusion.EJ2.Grids.Grid~AllowTextWrap.html

https://help.syncfusion.com/cr/aspnetmvc-js2/Syncfusion.EJ2~Syncfusion.EJ2.Grids.GridTextWrapSettingsBuilder~WrapMode.html